# Need a way to "flip" this char array for a game sprite to look to the left

Tags: java, arrays, char, sprite, swap

So, basically I need to find a good way to "flip" a char array used for a sprite in order to make him/it look to the left and vice versa. Here is my array ->

```
WARRIOR = (

" " +         
 "!!!!!     " +        
 "!!oo! ^   " +
 "!!!!! ^   " +
 "##### ^   " +
 "#######   " +
 "#####     " +
 "** **     ").toCharArray();
```

The display routine looks like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < WARRIOR.length; i++) {
        int x = (i - 1) % 10;
        int y = (i - 1) / 10;
        if (WARRIOR[i] == '!') {
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 204));
            g.fillRect(x_pos + x * 5, y_pos + y * 5, 5, 5);
        }
        else if (WARRIOR[i] == 'o') {
            g.setColor(new Color(204, 0, 0));
            g.fillRect(x_pos + x * 5, y_pos + y * 5, 5, 5);
        }
        // other characters here...
    }
}​
```

Comment: How do you know how many columns wide he is? Are all the sprites a fixed width? Also, what's up with the single leading space?

Comment: I use the leading space to "omit" the 0 element. This is entirely one dimension so no width, but I use the + and new lines for organizational purposes.

Comment: It's meant to be displayed as a two dimensional sprite, though, right? Does the display routine break lines every 10 characters, or what? Also you should probably tag your question with either .NET or Java, I just realized I have no idea what language this is.

Comment: This is java, also it doesn't break anything, it only tells that the next line is part of the array

Comment: What I'm saying is your game displays this more or less like it is displayed in the code, right? If so, how does it know where each row begins?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.brilliantsheep.com/3-ways-to-reverse-a-string-in-java/

Comment: Basically in a for loop, i do graphics.fillRect(x_player+x*5, y_player + y*5, 5, 5); where x = (i-1)%10; (i is variable in for-loop) and y = (i-1)/10; 10 is for the length of each 'row'

Comment: @user1322905 I think the answer is to have a flipped display routine that iterates `x` backwards (count down instead of up). Don't *store* a flipped sprite, just flip it as you display it.

Comment: @user1322905 if you want to add that display routine code from your last comment to the question, I'll play with it.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/13tZ9pPcLL9Spxub7foVQe33HTrhbk7SS6FL1tSeEWRE/edit

Comment: @user1322905 I've added a bit of the code to your question, I hope you don't mind. You can remove it if you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest having an alternate display routine to draw sprites backwards instead of storing a reversed copy of the sprite.

Try changing this line:

```
int x = (i - 1) % 10;
```

to this:

```
int x = 10 - (i - 1) % 10;
```

This should draw sprites backwards.

---

Also, you may want to take a look at the [XPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap) format, it is pretty similar to what you are doing.

Comment: @EranMedan I had to keep it simple, my Java knowledge is pretty much zero ;)

Comment: @GGG, you sir, thank you from the bottom of my java library. My mind is tired right now and therefore rendered useless. Would you care to explain the "10 -" to my feeble mind?

Comment: @user1322905 `for (var i = 1; i < 21; ++i) console.log((i - 1) % 10, 10 - (i - 1) % 10)` <-- type that in your browser's console and see if the output clears things up... the best way I know how to put it is `x` is "reversed."

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the data structure, here is a solution (I'm sure it can be improved but it works):

**Short version**

```
char[] flip = new char[warrior.length];

for(int i=0;i<warrior.length;i++){
    flip[9-i%10+ i/10*10] = warrior[i];   
}
```

**Long version**

```
    char[] warrior= (         
             "!!!!!     " +        
             "!!oo! ^   " +
             "!!!!! ^   " +
             "##### ^   " +
             "#######   " +
             "#####     " +
             "** **     ").toCharArray();

    for(int i=0;i<warrior.length;i++){
        if(i%10==0){
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print(warrior[i]);
    }

    char[] flip = new char[warrior.length];

    for(int i=0;i<warrior.length;i++){
        //9-: 0 goes to 9, 1 to 8 etc 
        //i: cycles from 0 to 9
        //i/10: provides the row (e.g. 25/10=2)
        //*10: gives me the 2d row in 1d array  

        flip[9-i%10+ i/10*10] = warrior[i]; 
    }


    for(int i=0;i<flip.length;i++){
        if(i%10==0){
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print(flip[i]);
    }
```

this will output

```
!!!!!     
!!oo! ^   
!!!!! ^   
##### ^   
#######   
#####     
** **     
     !!!!!
   ^ !oo!!
   ^ !!!!!
   ^ #####
   #######
     #####
     ** **
```

But i would use a different data structure (e.g. 2D array)
Or think of it as a matrix, and use the [example in this article](http://scriptche.blogspot.com/2011/04/take-mirror-image-of-int-array-in-java.html)

Comment: The OP wants to flip it on the X axis, but your solution would flip on the  Y axis (since presumably each row would be horizontal).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with this, would you care to explain this method along with its variables/parameters?

Comment: thanks, updated the answer. was a not trivial as I thought ;)

Comment: also I wrote this before knowing the display routine is X/Y based and not console output...

Answer (score 0):

You should consider handling your sprites in another way. For example, since you seem to be fond of char [], you could use a char [] [].
If your sprites always have the same width, you can consider something like that:

```
//Slices your WARRIOR into pieces
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
short i = 0;
for (final char a:WARRIOR) {
    if (++i != 10) {    //You should be able to find it
        builder.append(a);
    } else {
        i = 0;
        builder.append('\n');   //Line sep
    }
}

//Print the right oriented WARRIOR
System.out.println(builder);

//And flip it ! yay !
final String [] slicedWarrior = builder.toString().split("\n");   //Line sep
for (final String slice : slicedWarrior) {
    final char [] slicesOfSlice;
    for (int j = (slicesOfSlice = slice.toCharArray()).length - 1; j != 0; j--) {
        System.out.print(slicesOfSlice[j]);
    }
    System.out.print('\n');   //Line sep
}
```

Comment: With the OP update, this answer is not really relevant anymore even though it works... like a bulldozer.